# using the facebook c# sdk V. 6.x how can i acquire a list of all pages the user is admin on?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I would like to get all the pages Ids which the user is admin on i have this code but it doesn't seem to work

> ```
>   internal static IEnumerable<string> GetAllPages()
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             var fb = new FacebookClient(Settings.Default.AccessToken) { AppId =     CurrentValues.appId, AppSecret = CurrentValues.appSecret };
>             List<string> pagesIds = new List<string>();
>             dynamic results = fb.Get("/me/pages");
>             var _sb = new StringBuilder();
>             foreach (var result in results.data)
>             {
>                 pagesIds.Add(result.id);
>                 _sb.Append(result.id);
>                 _sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
>             }
>             MessageBox.Show(_sb.ToString());
>             return pagesIds;
>         }
>         catch 
>         {
>             MessageBox.Show("can't get all pages");
>             return null;
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 4):

I knew where the error is we should use fb.Get("/me/accounts"); instead of fb.Get("/me/pages");

such a silly mistake

here is the working code

> ```
> internal static IEnumerable<string> GetAllPages()
> {
>     try
>     {
>         var fb = new FacebookClient(Settings.Default.AccessToken) { AppId =     CurrentValues.appId, AppSecret = CurrentValues.appSecret };
>         List<string> pagesIds = new List<string>();
>         dynamic results = fb.Get("/me/accounts");           
>         foreach (var result in results.data)
>         {
>             pagesIds.Add(result.id);               
>         }          
>         return pagesIds;
>     }
>     catch 
>     {
>         MessageBox.Show("can't get all pages");
>         return null;
>     }
> }
> ```